# SuiteScript How to access the Revenue Recognition Details on the lines of the journal entries

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to access the details listing on the individual "lines" of Journal Entry Records in SuiteScript. When I look in debugger, the "details" column is not showing. Are the records for this column perhaps searchable in a "query" manner? Or is there some other way to gain access to that data?

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Via Suitescript to access the details on the individual lines you need to load or create the record, then access the sublist.  The sublist id is "line" per the [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/journalentry.html).  You can use the [N/record](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45152/kw/45152) or [N/currentRecord](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51496/kw/51496) module to get or set values.  See example below:

```
//load record OR create one 
var myJournal = record.load({
  type: record.Type.JOURNAL_ENTRY,
  id: 12345
});

//get line value
var lineAmount = myJournal.getSublistValue({
  sublistId: 'line',
  fieldId: 'amount',
  line: 0
});

//set line value
myJournal.setSublistValue({
  sublistId: 'line',
  fieldId: 'amount',
  line: 0, 
  value: 100
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I know how to access the "line" sublist items, but there is a details column on the sublist line  item that has a link that leads to a collection of  items. The link will say something like "8 Rows" and the heading to that column is "Details". When I look at the sublist row itself in the debugger, I cannot find that column. When you click it, it goes to a form entitled "Revenue Recognition Journal Details:JE5062" JE5062 being the Journal entry record you are linking from. This is one level deeper than you are thinking about. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Oh I see, my apologies.  I understand the question now.  We do not use this feature in my instance.  But I'm curious, when on the page entitled "Revenue Recognition Journal Details:JE5062", what's the url?  I ask, since the record type/id should be listed there.

Comment: The query portion of the URL is /app/accounting/transactions/revrec/revrecjournaldetail.nl?id=438406&line=0,  how to I find the actual type name of this? as you can see it is also referencing it is the "0" line as I had clicked the column in the first first line item in the sublist, I appreciate any help you may give, thanks

Comment: @amanda another thing I noticed is that when on the detail page, the list of detail items has a header just called journal entries, so they might be actually be just a view of "more" journal entry records

Comment: Usually before the ".nl?" is the record type/id, in this case it's "revrecjournaldetail" or similar to Revenue Recognition Journal Detail.  I cannot find this or any "revrec" items on the Records Browser, SuiteScript Supported Records (Suite Answer 10242), or Supported Transactions (Suite Answer 10507).  I'm officially stumped but will keep my mind open.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know I'm not losing it, but thanks for your help , if you think of something please let me know. Thanks